# Calculating textbox.text dynamically with two comboboxvalues

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, combobox, textbox

I have 2 Comboboxes, named cb1 and cb2, and 1 Textbox, named tb1.

So what I need to do : If any value is selected in both cb1 and cb2 at the same time,  tb1.text should be set to the value of cb1 divided by cb2.

The textbox should be left blank until 2 values are selected,
also the textbox value should change dynamically, when one of the selected items of the comboboxes is changed.

Could someone help me please? I have like no idea where to start..

I thought about declaring 3 variables, x and y for the comboboxes and z for the textbox. and then something like an if, which would set  x and y to the value dynamically to the selected ones..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start with the event that occurs when a combobox selection is made

Comment: I believe you are on the right track, why don't you show us some code and we can help you when you run into trouble. I would approach this much like you've suggested. Simply bind unique properties to each combobox and bind a third property to the division. You can trigger property changes independently.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

:)

I think this would help you a little bit, I did some code based on event `SelectedIndexChanged` associated to both comboBoxes, and validating that they're not empty. Take a look, I hope it helps you.

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
    //event triggered when SelectedIndexChanged
    protected void cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        //In this way you can compare the value and if it is possible to convert into an integer. 
        if (int.TryParse(cb1.SelectedItem.Text, out a) && int.TryParse(cb2.SelectedItem.Text, out b))
        {

            fillTextBox(a, b);
        }
    }

    protected void cb2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        if (int.TryParse(cb1.SelectedItem.Text, out a) && int.TryParse(cb2.SelectedItem.Text, out b))
        {
            fillTextBox(a,b);
        }
    }

    private void fillTextBox(int value1, int value2)
    {
        tb1.Text = (value1 / value2).ToString();
    }
```

Greetings :)

Comment: first of all thanks for your time, I appreciate it ! now Ive done it your way, but there are still some errors coming up.. it says to me that cb1.SelectedValue is type object and cant be converted into string.. :/ also this error : "the best overloaded method int.TryParse(string,out int) has some invalid arguments

Comment: that's because all depends of what Property are you using. If you want to use the "underground" value or index of a dropDownList you can use `SelectedValue` so if you want to use the value that you're currently "looking" you should use the proterty `SelectedItem.Text` I'll modify it then. I hope it helps

Comment: This is not good code. As WPF code in particular, it is very bad.

Comment: I accept any suggestion, what should I do for a better code? I'm still learning as you can see. @EdPlunkett

Comment: @PabloDurán Here's an example of the canonical way to do this in WPF: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34230720/424129

Comment: @EdPlunkett I appreciate it so much, thank you for helping me to improve

Answer (score 1):

There's an event on `ComboBox` control `SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`. You can attach the event on both your ComboBoxes in appliacation and then in the event handler check if values in both ComboBoxes are the same. If they are you can update `TextBox` with value also counted in the event handler.

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.Text == comboBox2.Text)
            textBox1.Text = "true";
        else
            textBox1.Text = "";
    }
```

The same event handler for both `ComboBoxes`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Question tags i believe you are working on a WPF application. 
May be you can do something like below.    register to the Selection changed events of cb1 and cb2. and in the handler and then call a  common method  which sets the value with calculation to the text box.

```
private void Cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
    System.EventArgs e)
{
        SetTextValue()
}

private void Cb2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
    System.EventArgs e)
{
    SetTextValue()
}

private void SetTextValue ()
(
//hope its int value that you are binding.
    var cb1value = (int) cb1.SelectedItem;
    var cb2value = (int) cb2.SelectedItem;

 tb1.Text = (cb1Value/cb2Value).toString();
)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: So, first of all, thanks for your reply! I just tried out your code, but Ive got an problem left.. I think I forgot to mention it. the comboboxes has strings selected by default.. like "Please choose!", and then just int values then.. now it gives me an exception, as SetTextValue cant be used properly. therefore id like to use like an if with boolean.. like if(cb1.SelectedItem != int) then .. and so on. ive already figured out that i have to use GetType(); but I have no clue how..